# scan page for particular html element and assign css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

if I have inside table following snippet of code

```
<td>TimeOfArrival</td>
```

how can I scan whole for this particular html and assign css like

```
<td class="myClass">TimeOfArrival</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to find the exact text for td and change its class.

```
$('td').filter(function(){
  return $(this).html() == "TimeOfArrival";
}).addClass("myClass");
```

If you are looking for tds that contains *TimeOfArrival* then you can use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) with td.

```
$( "td:contains('TimeOfArrival')" ).addClass( "myClass" );
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```
$( "td:contains('TimeOfArrival')" ).addClass( "myClass" );
```

Answer (score 0):

contains selector is a good idea but if it doesn't worked  because of any browser support issues or whatever reason you can always use this

```
$("td").each(function(
  if($(this).text() == 'TimeOfArrival'){
    $(this).addClass('myClass');
  }
))
```